# Dados POST não estão sendo enviados

Tags: php, apache, post

De um dia pro outro todos os sistemas contido no mesmo server deixaram de enviar os dados via post.

Já me certifiquei de que o `form` e o `script backend` (PHP) estejam correto, e está.
Justamente porque no dia anterior estava funcionando.

Imagino ser algum problema com o Apache.

Que ferramentas existem para diagnosticar e fazer debug neste tipo de problema/erro?

Comment: Retorna algum erro? como está seu código!

Comment: Qual era a versão do php?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Sua pergunta carece de mais detalhes. Poderia por favor compartilhar um trecho do og do seu apache?